# AJAX response 0 while sending API request using SOAP - php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, soap

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery.ajax
        ({
            url:    ajaxurl,
            type:   'POST',
            data:   {
                        action: 'shipping_data',
            },
             processData: false, 

            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                alert("failed.");
            }
        });
```

**PHP:**

```
function shipping_data()
{
// Testing for now. 
 $requestParams = array(
    'CityName' => 'Berlin',
    'CountryName' => 'Germany'
);

$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL');
echo  $response = $client->GetWeather($requestParams);
die();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_shipping_data', 'shipping_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_shipping_data', 'shipping_data' );
```

I use `processData: false,` and getting response 0. Before i was getting failed response. Why i can't getting the request? If I use SOAP outside the `shipping_data` function then i can get the response. But i want to use inside the `shipping_data` function (called using ajax) any help?

Comment: why do you have the `die()` in the function? I don't know about wordpress, but in the frameworks that I know better, a user defined function should just return some data and let the request as such be handled by the framework

Comment: Troubleshoot the actual request in network tab of browser console and report findings for status and response body text.

Answer (score 0):

0 is a default error code for ajax, doesn't matter what you do this is a hardcoded error.
most of the time when you use die(); it will break everything, try replacing it with

```
exit;
```